# Laravel Eloquent check for relationship between two specific models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have two models with a many to many relationship

Post and Category

I am trying to find out if a specific category belongs to a specific post.

I can see if a specific post has any categories, I'm tempted to just get all of the categories for the post and load it into an array then do an in_array check for the category I am looking for. Before I go that route is there a proper way to do this in Eloquent though?

Comment: Yeah, there is: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence. The `has()` or `whereHas()` methods allow you to check relationships while querying a Model.

Comment: The examples for has don;t show this specific use though. It only shows finding all of 1 model that has a relation to another model.

Comment: Well, you'd use that in tandem with a given `id`, although if you already know the `id` of the model you're looking for, the `has()` or `whereHas()` methods are generally not necessary. `Post::where('id', $id)->first()` _could_ return the same results as `Post::whereHas(...)->first()`. I guess I was unclear on your use case :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like so:

```
$post->categories()->where('id', $category->id)->exists();
```

Comment: Hmm. I think I see where you are going. But as is it throws an error: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select exists(select * from `categories` inner join `category_post` on `categories`.`id` = `category_post`.`category_id` where `category_post`.`post_id` = 1 and `id` = 2 order by `name` asc) as `exists`)" So I just had to change 'id' in the where to 'category_id'.